# Is it normal for a CNN model to get ~20% accuracy with a dataset that contains 60-80 images per class?

Tags: python, tensorflow, deep-learning, kaggle

I'm working with this Kaggle [chess pieces dataset](https://www.kaggle.com/datasets/niteshfre/chessman-image-dataset?datasetId=292862&sortBy=voteCount) but after I coded my model and ran it, it only achieved about 20% accuracy and stalled there. Is this normal if each class has less than 100 images to train? I did image augmentation as well. If this is the case, around how many images do I need for datasets like this?

This is my model structure:

```
model = tf.keras.models.Sequential([
  tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(32, (3,3), activation='relu', input_shape=(150, 150, 3)),
  tf.keras.layers.MaxPooling2D(2, 2),
  tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(32, (3,3), activation='relu'),
  tf.keras.layers.MaxPooling2D(2,2),
  
  tf.keras.layers.Flatten(),
  tf.keras.layers.Dense(512, activation='relu'),
  tf.keras.layers.Dense(6, activation = "softmax")
])

model.compile(
    loss = "sparse_categorical_crossentropy",
    optimizer = "rmsprop",
    metrics = ["accuracy"]
)
```

Comment: There's no way of knowing that except trying, since it depends on the problem (e.g. how much chess pieces resemble each other) and the images. Only thing that can be said is that 20% is barely higher than the 17% expected from random guessing, so it's clearly not a very good model. If you want to know what's normal, why not looking at other people's attempts?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like this person got up to around 40% validation accuracy: https://www.kaggle.com/code/diegofreitasholanda/chess-pieces-image-classification

But in general, yes that is a small dataset, and it will be hard to learn a good, generalizable network well, especially when the images all look very different from one another (I see some real pictures, others are clip art, etc).